# Browser-Sync not injecting CSS into Browser

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I used this gulp file until recently. Now everything still works, the CSS still gets compiled except injecting the compiled CSS back into the browser.

Thanks for your time!

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bs = require('browser-sync').create();

// Include plugins
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var minifycss = require('gulp-clean-css');
var streamqueue = require('streamqueue');

gulp.task('bs', function () {
   var files = [
      'libraries/file1.css',
   ];

   bs.init(files, {       
      proxy: 'localhost',
      port: '80',
      baseDir: './',
      startPath: 'joomla'
   })

   gulp.watch("libraries/file1.css", ['fcss']);

});

gulp.task('fcss', function() {
    var themes = ['.theme1','.theme2', '.theme3'];

    themes.forEach( function(theme) {
      return gulp.src(['libraries/'+theme+'.css', 
        'libraries/file1.css'
      ])
      .pipe(concat('style'+theme+'.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('media/css'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(minifycss({advanced:false, keepSpecialComments : 0}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('media/css'))

      .pipe(bs.stream());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running browsersync before you minify css:

```
gulp.task('fcss', function() {
    var themes = ['.theme1','.theme2', '.theme3'];

    themes.forEach( function(theme) {
      return gulp.src(['libraries/'+theme+'.css', 
        'libraries/file1.css'
      ])
      .pipe(concat('style'+theme+'.css'))
      .pipe(bs.stream())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('media/css'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(minifycss({advanced:false, keepSpecialComments : 0}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('media/css'));
   });
});
```

Comment: In a way, yes, timing. The way gulp streams work, means that each pipe is run sequentially. To work correctly, browser sync needs to receive a stream of uncompressed css (before minification).